# TeamCity Get svn url in msbuild script

Tags: teamcity

I'm using TeamCity 8 to run a msbuild script.

I thought TeamCity would set an environment variable or msbuild property with the vcs root url. But I can't find it.

I've tried running the script with /v:diag to get more info, and still can't find any property.

Can I get the url from Teamcity or do I have to run something like svn.exe info?

Comment: do you just want to add a vcs root to get your code?

Comment: Not sure I understand. I don't want to add anything, I want to know the subversion url that's currently beeing build and have already been setup in TeamCity

Comment: then looks at the settings tab for you build, or if you're an admin edit config settings - Version Control settings

Comment: I still don't understand, what am I looking for? *I* know the url, but I want the script to know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I'm currently doing.

TeamCity does have the variable, it's named %vcsroot.url%, but it's available to scrips as default.

To make it available in the msbuild script (and other types as well).

Goto project settings -> Parameters -> Add new parameter

```
Name: system.vcsroot.url
Kind: System property
Value: %vcsroot.url%
```

And you have property as $(vcsroot_url) in msbuild